# How to solve this Gas estimation failed error on Remix?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, remix

my code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.7.1;

import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";

contract UniswapExample {                           
  address internal constant UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D ;
  IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
  address private multiDaiKovan = 0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D;

  constructor() {
    uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS);
  }

  function convertEthToDai(uint daiAmount) public payable {
    uint deadline = block.timestamp + 15; // using 'now' for convenience, for mainnet pass deadline from frontend!
    uniswapRouter.swapETHForExactTokens{ value: msg.value }(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI(), address(this), deadline);
    
    // refund leftover ETH to user
    (bool success,) = msg.sender.call{ value: address(this).balance }("");
    require(success, "refund failed");
  }
  
  function getEstimatedETHforDAI(uint daiAmount) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return uniswapRouter.getAmountsIn(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI());
  }

  function getPathForETHtoDAI() private view returns (address[] memory) {
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
    path[1] = multiDaiKovan;
    
    return path;
  }
  
  //add Harry
  function getaddresWETH() public view returns (address WETHaddress){
      return uniswapRouter.WETH();
  }
  
  //add Harry
  function getAmountsETHforDAI(uint daiAmount) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(daiAmount, getPathForETHtoDAI());  
  }
  
 
  
  
}
```

i input input 100000000000000000 on convertEthToDai function then,
i saw this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzqbF.png)

how to solve the problem?

and this is remix setting
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZWFR.png)